# Xcode 15 Error mounting image — Disk image transfer is already in progress

Tags: xcode, xcode15, ios17

I recently updated to Xcode 15 Beta 7, and I'm having this error when running the app to my device (iOS 17 beta 7). It says that an existing disk image transfer is already in progress.

> **Waiting to reconnect to my iPhone 13 Pro**
>
> Previous preparation error: The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device.. Error mounting image: 0xe8000124
> (kAMDMobileImageMounterExistingTransferInProgress : An existing disk image transfer is already in progress.)

[image: Xcode error]

Comment: It's a beta. You are a beta tester for Apple. File a bug report with Apple.

Comment: still an issue on ios 17.0.3 non beta

Comment: Yeah, I've been stuck with this for hours now. Tried 3 different phones, no luck...

Answer (score 14):

To reset Trusted Computers:

- Go to Phone Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers.
- Now install the app again and you'll need to click 'trust' on the dialog again.

Wait until cache symbols are completed. Here is what you will see.

[image]

And it worked for me. Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: In addition to this, I had to restart the iPhone (and Xcode just in case), then it worked

Comment: Thank you! Encountered this issue today again and tried your comment and it worked :)

Comment: I restarted my iPhone, then did this, and it worked. I didn't have to restart xcode.

Answer (score 8):

What I have done and its worked for me

- Restart iPhone
- Restart Xcode

Then that error was gone

Answer (score 6):

On Xcode 15 click Device/Simulator Selector

- **Manage Run Destinations**
- **Find your device click with Right Button and "Unpair Device"**
- **Reconnect your device and "Trust" The Computer Again**

It solved my problem !

Comment: Use text highlighting for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today as well. I was running Xcode 15 beta 5 and updated to 8. That didn't do the trick, so I restarted my iPhone running beta 8. That seemed to do it! Might have been a combination of both or just the phone restart. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, iOS 17 (Beta 7) is the issue. I tried running the app on a device that has iOS 17 (Beta 4) and there were no errors.